# How do I fit a nonlinear function correctly in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following table, named "test":

```
    0.0037071        0.5 
     0.015203          1 
     0.035039        1.5 
     0.062272          2 
     0.093988        2.5 
      0.12776          3 
      0.16291        3.5 
      0.19991          4 
      0.24002        4.5 
      0.28574          5 
      0.34696        5.5 
      0.47879          6 
       1.8882     6.1125
```

Now I want do fit a nonlinear function using matlab:

```
modelfun = @(b,x)erf(b(1)*x)./b(2) + b(3);
beta0 = [0, 0, 0];
mdl = fitnlm(test,modelfun,beta0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error using nlinfit (line 247)
No usable observations after removing NaNs in Y and in the result of evaluating MODELFUN at the initial value BETA0.
```

How can I solve this ?
(and how can I get the final fitted nonlinear function for plotting ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `fitnlm`, but you can use another function from the optimization toolbox, e.g. [`lsqnonlin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html).

```
% splitting your data in vectors
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);

% the model you want to fit
modelfun = @(b,x) erf(b(1)*x)./b(2) + b(3);

% define a cost function, the error between the data to fit and the
% prediction of the model
cost_fun = @(b,x,y) modelfun(b,x) - y;

% initial guess
beta0 = [1 1 1];

% perform optimization
p = lsqnonlin(@(p) cost_fun(p,x,y), beta0);
```

---

Turns out that your model returns NaN values for `beta0` all zeros. This is why you get the error. This is caused by the fact that you are dividing by 0 initially, `b(2) = 0`. Changing your `beta0` to ones, solves the issue, and you can use `fitnlm`:

```
% splitting your data in vectors
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);

modelfun = @(b,x) erf(b(1)*x)./b(2) + b(3);

% initial guess
beta0 = [1 1 1];
mdl = fitnlm(x,y,modelfun,beta0)
```

---

To plot the data, just extract the parameters from the table in `mdl` and store them in `b_est` (first column), and do `y_est = modelfun(b_est,x)`. In case you use `lsqnonlin` they are stored in the output variable `p`

Then just plot: `plot(t,y,t,y_est)`

Comment: Do you know how to plot the fit funtion togehter witht the data ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It tells me "Wrong number of arguments." I think it's because "test" is a table...

Comment: @james, oh yeah thats right, you should split your table in vectors to do so, like I did at the top of my answer